# Visual Studio 2017 Project Template + VSIX: Image not included when creating a new project?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, vsix, project-template

Working on my first VS 2017 project template, following these steps:

- Created an empty class library project, the project includes an image in the root
- Exported template - verified that the .zip file contains the image
- Created a VSIX project and added the zip as the project template asset - verified that .vsix contains the image (after renaming it to zip)

After installing VSIX and creating a project from New Project, all seems to be well, except the image is not included in the project, i.e. the file is not there.

If it makes any difference, this is a .NET Core project targeting multiple frameworks (i.e. the image file is not explicitly specified in the project).

The .vstemplate file does contain it as a project item:

```
<TemplateContent>
    <Project TargetFileName="ClassLibrary.csproj" File="ClassLibrary.csproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
            <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="false" TargetFileName="icon.ico">icon.ico</ProjectItem>
    </Project>
</TemplateContent>
```

Any ideas what I may have missed?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order for items to copy to the template-created project they must also be included in the `.csproj` file and Visible not hidden.

Is your icon.ico in your `.csproj` file too?